# Javascript: usage of require in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I am quite new to javascript and I am struggling with a simple problem. I have to split up codes into separate files. As an example I have a file called Database.js. In that file I have the following lines:

```
function Database(){
    //someStuff
    this.fetchAll = function(){
        //some stuff
        return something;
    }
}
```

Now I want to use the Database.js code in the file app.js. So I write the following code in app.js:

```
var Database = require('Database');
var myDB = new Database();
var result = myDB.fetchAll();
```

However, I get the error `Script Error = '[object Database]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Database()') at app.js (line 3).`

What is my mistake?

Comment: I am using appcelerator from titanium. They write that they use the CommonJS Module Specification which is based on that of node.js.

Comment: @mkn: Please try to put tags related to your questions so that others can avoid confusions:)

Comment: @Anand: Yes, I apologize for my unprofessional post. I did not realize that I posted about something that is very specific.

Answer (score 5):

Before you moving to the development, you need to understand thoroughly about [CommonJS Modules in Titanium](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium). Then it will be more simple for you. Also refer the [require function](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Global-method-require)

Let's come to your error. `[ERROR] [object Database]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Database()') at app.js (line 3)` means that the module you created is not constructor. Your constructor function might not return any value. **Read [simple usage of CommonJS module](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium#CommonJSModulesinTitanium-SimpleUsage)**. I'm sure it will resolve your issue.

There is an alternative way, you can include your Database.js file in your app.js. You does not need to return anything and no need to use require function. You just need to use the [include method](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium-method-include). Just write `Ti.include('Database.js');` inside your app.js and you can access all the global variables and functions inside the Database.js file

Comment: You're welcome, If it resolved your issue  please put the tick mark

Answer (score 2):

This question is old but it has not been answered yet. So i will just provide the answer for anyone who is visiting here.

You have to export you function as global. To do so you would declare it as below

```
exports.fetchAll = function Database(){
  //some stuff
  return something;
};
```

You can also declare the function so that it can be used globally as well as locally within the file

```
var fetchAll = function Database(){
  //some stuff
  return something;
};
exports.fetchAll = fetchAll;
```

Then assuming the file name is Database and it is in same folder as app.js, you can use it as below

```
var Database = require('Database');
var result = Database.fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

**edit: This answer is javascript general and it's not oriented towards Appacelerator Titanium.**

---

There is no such `include` or `require` in javascript. You can on the other hand do one of the following

**Include a script tag before your script to include Database.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Database.js" >
```

OR

**Add it dynamically**

```
function loadScript(url, callback)
{
    // adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.src = url;

   // then bind the event to the callback function 
   // there are several events for cross browser compatibility
   script.onreadystatechange = callback;
   script.onload = callback;

   // fire the loading
   head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: There is one in Node.js, which is why it would be kinda relevant to know if the OP uses it.

Comment: Yea, but he didn't even bother setting a question tag for it. So, the answer goes general.

Comment: If whatever environment he uses didn't have `require()`, he would have gotten an error message from that line, not from the line after it.

Comment: Whatever fw he is uses, the classic plain js way of including scripts works. If he doesn't mention that he uses require.js or node.js, then the answer has to assume he doesn't.

Comment: @deadlock: This code has written for Appcelerator Titanium. Here we don't need to add script tag.

Comment: @Anand The OP edited the question. He didn't mention that he is using Titanium.

Comment: @deadlock: Okay. That made confusion between you guys because I couldn't see any titanium related answers here.

Comment: @Anand yea it's the OP fault that's why the questions got two downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be the usage of the variable name 'Database'. Maybe there is somewhere a name collusion.

I am sorry that I did not know that the usage of require is not a basic concept of js.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guess here. If you use CommonJS then you have to tell what should be available outside of the module. The way you lay out that you have made the Database "object" you would need to add:

```
module.exports = Database;
```

somewhere in your module. I always put them at the end - but not sure that is a requirement.

You can also make individual functions available outside of a module by specifying:

```
exports.getMyDatabase = getMyDatabase;
```

Where "getMyDatabase" is a function you have specified in the module. I use this way to "hide" certain implementation details of some functions from the outside and just make available the functions I want the developer to be able to call ;-)

/John

Answer (score -4):

I think this is the right usage of require js:

```
require(["Database"], function() {
    var myDB = new Database();
    var result = myDB.fetchAll();
});
```

http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

Comment: also notice , that "Database" - is the file name and it should be on the main folder of your project.

the require will search for Database.js file to load.

Comment: Assuming the OP uses require.js.